# Java: Design pattern for Pre and Post processing like Servlet filters offer

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need help in figuring out a design pattern. Requirements are as below:

1. MUST have a provision to support Pre processing before method call. Any one can extend API and add pre-processors
2. Similar to above but want Post processing

Closest example I can think of is Servlet filters which can be used to do pre and post processing but I want to do that in a simple Java application which will not be deployed on a server

Comment: Okay. And what is your question?

Comment: Simple, need suggestion which design pattern I can use in simple java code for pre and post processing capabilities

Comment: I searched on internet where I got suggestions like decorator but I believe can't it be more generic and simple and if possible transparent to calling client

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to put that additional info there?

Comment: JAX-RS gives you exactly that: a very easy way to add such interceptors and filters, on a very fine granular way. And the jersey server is extremely lightweight. Sure, that means we are talking about RESTful endpoints, but hey: that is a reasonable solution to most things in 2019 anyway. So ask yourself if the benefit of re-inventing such a framework really is worth all the cost that comes with it.

Comment: I have used jersey but the requirement is there because we are kind of developing a framework which which will not be used on a app server and hence the limitation

Comment: sounds like a decorator to me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 2):

As far design pattern is considered, you can use Proxy design pattern which provides the ability to process before and after. You can check cglib dynamic proxy or you can learn more about AOP(Aspect oriented programming) for pre and post operation on a method. Still if you are interested to achieve the same with core java only, you can use JDK dynamic proxy using invocation handler. I provide complete example, please go through it.

AOP using dynamic proxy : https://github.com/debjava/aopusingjdkdynamicproxy

**Pre-Processing :** https://github.com/debjava/aopusingjdkdynamicproxy/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ddlab/rnd/aop/BeforeHandler.java

**Post-Processing:** https://github.com/debjava/aopusingjdkdynamicproxy/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ddlab/rnd/aop/AfterHandler.java

Apart from that, you can refer to the comments.

Comment: Let me go through the example but I really liked the idea of aspect oriented way. Thinking why didn't I think of this.